# OSX on Windows on an Apple Computer

Tags: macos, xamarin, virtual-machine

I have a macbook pro apple computer, but I run windows (Bootcamp) with visual studio.

I want to trial Xamarin which need a host to a OSX OS to compile iOS apps.

I know I can open mavericks and run windows on a VM, but I want something that looks somehow strange because I couldn't find any guide to set up a osx os on windows (except for those trying to make it work on non-apple device)

How can I setup a VM or a build host for that matter to run on windows?
NOTE: this IS an apple computer and I can already double boot to osx.

Thanks.

Comment: as far as I know you cannot run OSX in Virtual Box or Vmware workstation on a windows host.  You can run WIndows inside vmware fusion. which would be the more "normal" way of doing it.  As most people don't buy macbooks to run windows on them :)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of ways you can install Mac OS X on a VM, but that requires a lot of unofficial hacks.  Also the OS X license states that it must run on Mac Hardware, so officially (also read as "easily"), you won't be able to run in on a VM from a Windows host.

However, since you stated that you already have a Macbook Pro with Windows installed via a Bootcamp partition, you can still use either VMWare Fusion or Parallels to launch your Windows Bootcamp Partition while you're still running in the Mac OS X environment.

Here are some links:

[Launching Bootcamp Partitions with VMWare Fusion](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1014618)

[Launching Bootcamp Partitions with Parallels](http://kb.parallels.com/en/112941)

Comment: Yes I know. But I only need the mac for the build process of Xamarin and I had to boot into OS X and also buy a software that is not cheap and its of no use for me. Guess I'll stick to develop only for android.